# Can't render 2048x1152

Tags: rendering, camera

I'm trying to make a render for a YouTube banner-thingy.
I tried to change the camera resolution to 2048x1152, for some reason during the render process it minimizes to 1024x577,
Any idea for the fix?

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Render size", change the " 50%" to 100%